# Swift How to stop current running Voice Output of AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

In my app I have a behavior where it can happen that 2 AVSpeech synthesizers are playing at the same time and would therefore overlap. In this case, is there a way to cancel all voice output currently being played as soon as a new voice output is started? Thanks very much!
This is my code:

```
    func makeVoiceOutput(_ text: String) {
    let spech = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
    spech.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: Locale.current.languageCode)
    
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synth.speak(spech)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AVSpeechSynthesizer` documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avspeechsynthesizer/ says:

> If the synthesizer is speaking, the synthesizer adds utterances to a
> queue and speaks them in the order it receives them.

So you should add your speech texts to an instance of `AVSpeechSynthesizer` that you create once, and not create a new one every time in your func. That should lead to queueing the spoken texts one after another.

Alternatively using `isSpeaking` and `stopSpeaking` you can also stop the current speech output.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer() // create once

    @State private var input = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Text", text: $input)
            Button("Speak") {
                makeVoiceOutput(input)
            }
            Button("Stop") {
                stopVoiceOutput()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeVoiceOutput(_ text: String) {
        let spech = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        spech.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: Locale.current.languageCode)
//        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synth.speak(spech)
    }
    
    func stopVoiceOutput() {
        synth.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It just worked that I placed my AVSpeechSynthesizer instance outside of the function